# Why does the algorithm not get in the function ? (or sometimes does but very late)

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing in Node.JS and I don't understand why the code works or not depending on the situation:

```
function readContent() {
  var l;
   fs.readFileSync('Shared/feb_index.txt', function (err, data) {
    data = data.toString("utf-8");
    console.log(data);
    const i = parseInt(data);
    l = i;
    console.log(l); 
    l ++;
    index_feb = String(l);
    console.log(l); 
    fs.writeFile(path = 'Shared/feb_index.txt', index_feb, function (err, data) {} );
    console.log("l dans read file" +l);
  })
  console.log("l avant return "+l);
  //return l;
}
```

With this code, when I call the function like this, I have the following output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7pBq.png)
As you can see, it gets first in "l avant return" and **never** displays "l dans read file".

I removed Sync in readFileSync, but then I got the following output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQmSJ.png)
It never shows the line "l avant return"

I am not able to understand why... I would like to console.log both the elements.

Thank you for any help !

Comment: [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) doesn't take a function as second argument. [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) however does. Your current function block is never executed.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's working !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to NullDev, here is the final code:
var index_feb;

```
function readContent() {
  var l;
  const data = fs.readFileSync('Shared/feb_index.txt',{encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
   
    const i = parseInt(data);
    l = i;
    l ++;
    index_feb = String(l);
    fs.writeFile(path = 'Shared/feb_index.txt', index_feb, function (err, data) {} );
}
```